# Am I right in interpreting the sentence in bold?

Tags: phrase-meaning, interpretation

> At night I lay awake looking at the darkness, listening to the silence,
> prefiguring the future, picking out of the past the scraps I had overlooked,
> those rejected events which now came to the foreground, large and
> important, so that the weight of destiny no longer bore on the current
> problems of my life, whatever they were at the time (for who lives without
> problems every day? Why waste the nights on them?).
> **Often, it is a far cry from Kensington and the early 1950s, this scene of
> my night-watch**. But even now when I return to London, to Kensington, and
> have paid the taxi and been greeted by the people waiting there, and have
> telephoned the friends and opened the mail, that night I find again my hours
> of sweet insomnia and know that it is a far cry from that Kensington of the
> past, that Old Brompton Road, that Brompton Road, that Brompton
> Oratory, a far cry.

I found two meanings for the "far cry" in the dictionary:
1:a long distance
2:something notably different

So I get somehow confused about the meaning of the sentence in bold. I think it mean: At night she think of somewhere very different from Kensington and the early 1950s. Am I right?

Source: A Far Cry From Kensington by Muriel Spark

Comment: You are correct in your interpretation of "far cry," but maybe not quite about it being somewhere she is thinking about at night. In this sentence, "it" is clarified later as "this scene of my night-watch." I think it means the place/scene where she is while lying in bed thinking, not the place she is thinking about.

Comment: I thought she is imaging herself in her thoughts somewhere very different from Kensington. Maybe I am not right because now I think the answer of @Justin can be true. I would be thankful of any other answer.

Comment: @Justin by reading the next lines I think you are correct.

Comment: Also, it could be confusing because later in the paragraph present-day Kensington is compared with with 1950's Kensington (the later uses of "far cry").